# How get selected column from nested relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using a query to get data from nested relation from the second relation I am getting selected data but from first relation, it is getting all the columns

```
Invoice::where('id',4)->with(['customers:id,name','consignments_invoices.charges:id,object_id,income'])->get();
```

I want to get selected columns from `consignments_invoices`

how i could do it?

Comment: See this work? `consignments_invoices.charges:id as con_id`.  For accessing the same name variable, use `as`.

Comment: i just want to access selected column from relation

Comment: can you mention each model fields seperately which you wanted to select

Comment: You need to also specify what columns you want from `consignments_invoices` by adding that to the `with` parameters however as a minimum you need to include the column that will be used to join with `charges` (if it's a 1-many relationship)

Comment: can you please give example in answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the meaning of the question correctly. This is my example with query builder:

```
$reqs = DB::table('users_request')
            ->select('users_request.id as id', 'users_request.user_id as userid', 'req_title', 'req_content', 'cat_id', 'categories.cat_name', 'username')
            ->join('categories', 'users_request.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->join('users', 'users_request.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->get()->toArray();
```

And for getting data I'm using as below:

```
print_r($reqs[5]->userid);
```